# ohLibspotify not calling any callback after login

Tags: c#, libspotify

I'm trying to create a project where I use the ohLibspotify .Net libspotify wrapper to login to spotify and stream playlists.

As far as I can see I've set everything up the same way like in the example. First create a session like so:

```
SpotifySessionConfig sp_config = new SpotifySessionConfig()
        {
            ApiVersion = 12,
            CacheLocation = "cache",
            SettingsLocation = "settings",
            UserAgent = "player",
            ApplicationKey = Properties.Resources.appkey,
            Listener = new sp_Listener()
        };
sp_session = SpotifySession.Create(sp_config);
```

Then I call `relogin()` if that fails than I show the login window to the user because no stored credentials have been found. When the user has supplied me with his account details I call `login(username, password, true, null)`. After that I'm awaiting a call back to the `sp_Listener` class.

In the `sp_Listener` class I have overridden the following functions:

```
SpotifySessionListener.LoggedIn(SpotifySession session, SpotifyError error)
SpotifySessionListener.ConnectionError(SpotifySession session, SpotifyError error)
SpotifySessionListener.LogMessage(SpotifySession session, string data)
```

The only callback that gets called is the `LogMessage` callback. I've hooked it up to log4net to read all the output efficiently. This is all of the `LogMessage`output:

```
2015-02-22 20:58:38,636 [18] DEBUG Namespace.sp_Listener - 19:58:38.634 I [c:/Users/spotify-buildagent/BuildAgent/work/1e0ce8a77adfb2dc/client/core/session/offline_authorizer.cpp:297] Unable to login offline: no such user

2015-02-22 20:58:38,649 [18] DEBUG Namespace.sp_Listener - 19:58:38.649 I [c:/Users/spotify-buildagent/BuildAgent/work/1e0ce8a77adfb2dc/client/core/session/offline_authorizer.cpp:297] Unable to login offline: no such user

2015-02-22 20:58:38,651 [14] DEBUG Namespace.sp_Listener - 19:58:38.649 E [c:/Users/spotify-buildagent/BuildAgent/work/1e0ce8a77adfb2dc/client/core/network/proxy_resolver_win32.cpp:215] WinHttpGetProxyForUrl failed

2015-02-22 20:58:38,664 [19] DEBUG Namespace.sp_Listener - 19:58:38.661 I [ap:1752] Connecting to AP ap.gslb.spotify.com:4070

2015-02-22 20:58:38,713 [19] DEBUG Namespace.sp_Listener - 19:58:38.713 I [ap:1226] Connected to AP: 193.182.7.34:4070
```

It seems like I must have forgotten something. I've no idea what, maybe one of you guys knows a solution.

Comment: Are you calling sp_session.ProcessEvents?

Comment: You sir, just saved some German's life! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the original author of the ohLibSpotify wrapper library. I think you possibly have overlooked the need to call ProcessEvents. ohLibSpotify tries as far as possible to provide only a thin layer over libspotify. Almost everything in the libspotify docs remains relevant when you are using ohLibSpotify, and you should consider those docs your first port-of-call. https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.51/index.html

In particular:

> The library itself uses multiple threads internally. To allow for synchronization between these threads, you must implement the sp_session_callbacks::notify_main_thread callback. Whenever called (from some internal thread), the application must wake up the main loop so the sp_session_process_events() function can be run.
>
> The API itself is not thread-safe. Thus, you must take care not to call the API functions from more than one of your own threads.

The names are slightly different, but the concepts are the same - you need to implement NotifyMainThread to get notifications that libspotify wants to communicate with you, then you need to make sure that your main thread calls sp_session.ProcessEvents. You also need to make sure that only one thread ever interacts with ohLibSpotify at a time, either by coordinating so that only one thread calls ohLibSpotify, or by using appropriate locks around calls into ohLibSpotify.

(I'm using libspotify names here: the following advice applies equally whether you're using libspotify directory or ohLibSpotify.)

With a few exceptions, libspotify only ever calls your callbacks from inside a call to sp_session_process_events. (The exceptions are notify_main_thread and the callbacks associated with music delivery.) So if you're not set up to call that regularly, you'll find that libspotify doesn't do very much. If your program has an event loop, you should arrange to send yourself events whenever you receive the notify_main_thread callback or when the time specified by your last call to sp_session_process_events has passed, and call sp_session_process_events in the event handler. If you have no event loop, you might want to spawn a thread for this purpose, and make sure to use appropriate locks to stop other threads from calling into libspotify at the same time.